# dopar foreach (running a parallel for loop)

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

This question is specifically related to running a for loop on multiple cores. I am trying to learn how to run a code using parallel cores. The actual code is somewhat complicated so I am recreating **a very basic and diluted code here**. Note this example is only for illustrative purposes and not the actual code.

```
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

#Creating a mock dataframe
Event_ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
Type=c("A","B","C","D","E","A","B","C","D","E","A","B","C","D")
Revenue1=c(24,9,51,7,22,15,86,66,0,57,44,93,34,37)
Revenue2=c(16,93,96,44,67,73,12,65,81,22,39,94,41,30)
z = data.frame(Event_ID,Type,Revenue1,Revenue2)
#replicates z 5000 times
n =5000
zz=do.call("rbind", replicate(n, z, simplify = FALSE))
zz$Revenue3 = 0

#################################################################
#   **foreach, dopar failed attempt**
#################################################################
cl=parallel::makeCluster(14,type="PSOCK") #I have 8 core 16 threads but use 14 here. Please edit this accordingly.
registerDoParallel(cl)
home1 = function(zz1){
  foreach(i=1:nrow(zz1), .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
    zz1[i,'Revenue3'] = sqrt(zz1[i,'Revenue1'])+(zz1[i,'Revenue2'])
  }
  return(zz1)
}

zzz = home1(zz1=zz)
stopCluster(cl) 

#################################################################
#Non parallel implementation
#################################################################
home2 = function(zz2){
  zz3=zz2
  for (i in 1:nrow(zz3)){
    zz3[i,'Revenue3'] = sqrt(zz3[i,'Revenue1'])+(zz3[i,'Revenue2'])
  }
  return(zz3)
}
zzzz=home2(zz2=zz)
```

I create a dataframe and try to use foreach and dopar but it does not seem to work. Next I provide the implementation of the non parallel version of the code. However, the parallel version does not work for me. The output df that I get is same as the input matrix. I realize that I might be making a basic mistake, but I am not experienced enough to figure out what exactly is wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. I do realize that my non-parallel version is not optimal and can be improved but this is used for an example.

Comment: You might want to read https://privefl.github.io/blog/a-guide-to-parallelism-in-r/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that running in parallel using the `parallel`, `doParallel` or `foreach` package is somewhat limited, when it comes overwriting values in existing data.frames. When performing the parallelization by this package, is starting a parallel running R session, a worker, which performs the calculation returning whatever result was performed in some convenient form. Meaning that these worker sessions contains none of the objects in the original session unless provided (with .export or as a function argument). The `future`, `promises` and `ipc` packages can allow for asynchronous processing while modifying variables within the original session at the cost of some simplicity.

Note that as each session will utilize a seperate core, using more sessions than cores reduce performance overall.

As for the implementation itself, how you want to approach parallelization depends on what you need for your calculations and which format you want to return. If you want to perform simple row wise calculations, you could use something like:

```
library(iterators)
cl=parallel::makeCluster(4) #I have 8 core 16 threads but use 14 here. Please edit this accordingly.
registerDoParallel(cl)
stopCluster(cl)
home1 <- function(zz1){
  output <- foreach(x = iter(zz1, by = "row"), .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
    x[["Revenue3"]] <- sqrt(x[["Revenue1"]]) + x[["Revenue2"]]
    x
  }
  output
}
zzz <- home1(zz1=zz)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Note that i have used the Iterator structure here, which can be used to iterate efficiently over rows/columns. If this is the type of calculations you are looking for, i suggest going for a vectorized approach however, as this will improve performance drastically.

```
zz[["Revenue3"]] <- sqrt(zz[["Revenue2"]) + zz[["Revenue1"]]
```

The latter being roughly 13000 times faster on my tiny 4 core laptop.

Comment: Awesome. That worked. One quick follow up question. Suppose I wanted to do this multiple times (eg. 1000) would I need to do anything after running the loop once? Would I need to create the clusters and the stopCluster for each time I ran the loop? @Oliver

Comment: If you dont close it, it will stay active after each run. 
Just dont run stopCluster and it will keep using the same cluster repeatably.